# How do I write an excel formula to count the number of a value in one column based off of a date in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet and I'm trying to do a simple Count function, probably a countif but I'm unsure how to go about writing the formula.

I have two columns that I'd like to use for this formula.

Column N - I would like to filter for the Criteria of "C" or anytime a cell has a value of C

Column 0 - This column has dates filled in (short date format).

I would like to get a count of every C for each month, as simple as that.

[image]

In this example I filtered the date for May of 2017 and filtered for C under the Check column. We can see that there are 12 instances of C showing in the month of May 2017.

Does anyone know how to structure a formula that I would be able to Count the Number of C's for every month into the foreseeable future?

I figured out how to count the total present in a date range but unsure of how to add the date range plus Column N (Check) every time "C" is present in the cell.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O:O>=DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"))*(O:O<=DATEVALUE("5/31/2017")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=COUNTIFS(O1:O100,">="&A1,O1:O100,"<"&B1,N1:N100,"C")
```

Where `A1` has the start date and `B1` has the end date for that month. You can use `DATEVALUE()` instead of `A1` and `B1`. Change as applicable

**Screenshot**
[image]

If you want to use `SUMPRODUCT` then see this

`=SUMPRODUCT((O:O>=DATEVALUE("1/5/2017"))*(O:O<=DATEVALUE("30/5/2017"))*(N:N="C"))`

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed! What would the syntax be without referencing A1 and B1? Like if I just put in the actual formula 5/1/2017 and 5/31/2017???

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(O1:O100,">="&DATEVALUE("1/5/2017"),O1:O100,"<"&DAT‌​EVALUE("30/5/2017"),‌​N1:N100,"C")` I have give you both Countifs and Sumproduct. You may have to refresh the page to see it. BTW you may have to write the date in reverse for example `DATEVALUE("5/1/2017")` or `DATEVALUE("5/30/2017")` if the above didn't work for you

Comment: Roul ...................... I tried the =COUNTIFS and keep getting an error...........Thank you for taking the time and trying to help me!

Comment: Can you post here the exact formula that you are using?

Comment: =COUNTIFS(O1:O1050,">="&DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"),O1:O1050,"<"&DAT‌​‌​EVALUE("5/31/2017"‌​),‌​N1:N1050,"C")

Comment: What about `=COUNTIFS(O1:O1050,">="&DATEVALUE("1/5/2017"),O1:O1050,"<"&D‌AT‌​‌​EVALUE("31/5/2‌​017"‌​),‌​N1:N1050,"‌​C")`

Comment: Also an error................ I noticed in the first part of the statement that the tool-tip in excel says"(date_text)" when I click on the date portion of the formula however in the second part of the statement it doesn't show that when I'm in the date portion of ("31/5/2017")

Comment: Yeah. I realised it. one moment,. testing the formula before posting it

Comment: Try `=COUNTIFS(O1:O1050,">="&DATEVALUE("1/5/2017"),O1:O1050,"<"&DATEVALUE("31/5/2017"),N1:N1050,"C")` or `=COUNTIFS(O1:O1050,">="&DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"),O1:O1050,"<"&DATEVALUE("5/31/2017"),N1:N1050,"C")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147642/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-motorhead1308).

Answer (score 0):

In another column (lets say 'P' for example) I would insert a formula to give you the month number `=Month(P7)` - this will return 5 for May.

I would then use COUNTIFS (Like COUNTIF but it uses multiple criteria) to count where column N contains 'C' and column 'P' contains '5'.

`=COUNTIFS(N:N,"C",P:P,5)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this....you need to select the entire Column B and named the column as 'Date'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1FLk.png)